How can I get the height of my Title bar in bash
I am working on a pet project which involves knowing the height of the title bar on different Linux Mint PC's, I realise the size depends on the Window Title Font and probably some CSS, so it will probably change from PC to PC. I have searched for the answer, but I can't seem to nail it down, I'm sure it is easily found, but where!
I am currently running Mint 21.3 and have xdotool installed.
I am very new to Bash scripting and I'm also knocking on a fair bit, so nothing comes easy to me, but after some research and about eight hours of trial and error I have come up with this...

sleep .05
id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
xdotool windowmove $id 0 0
sleep .05
y=$(xprop -root '_NET_WORKAREA')
y=$(($(xwininfo -id $id|grep -oP "(?<=Absolute upper-left Y:).*") - $(echo ${y#=}|cut -d, -f2)))

read -n1 -p "Title Bar = $y"

This does actually work, I needed to add the two sleep .05 too ensure xdotool, xprop and wininfo didn't execute too fast and cause the window move to fail and/or the result to be '0', which it occasionally did before I added them. Please let me know if there is a much much simpler way to do this, echo $TITLEBAR perhaps!
I need the sleep right at the beginning of the script because the id=$(xdotool getactivewindow) gives the id of the previous window which at that point, is still the active window, I need to wait for my terminal to become the active window, my script fails 100% of the time without the sleep. Bash is very new to me so any tips and tricks are most welcome, I'll add the quotes to variables. I need the ${y#=} to remove everything up to the "=" from my variable "y", there are probably dozens of better ways to obtain the values after the "=" but this is the only way I know. As for the readability of my script, I do tend to compact everything, (sorry about that!) The read at the end to show the result was just my way of pausing the script to see what the result was, a couple of weeks ago I couldn't even get the newbie's "Hello World" to work, it was working, but the window ran and closed in a flicker of black and I had no idea what was wrong!
I have made the alterations you advised and here is my second attempt.
#!/bin/bash

id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
echo "Id = "$id" Wrong One!!"

sleep .08 # .05 was not quite enough, it occasionally failed.
id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
echo -e "Id = "$id"\n"

xdotool windowmove $id 0 0

sleep .05 # Prevent xprop from giving pre-move results.
workarea=$(xprop -root "_NET_WORKAREA")

# Strip everything before the values.
workarea=${workarea#*=}

top_panel=$(echo "$workarea" | cut -d, -f2)
echo "Top Panel = "$top_panel

# Get height of top panel + header bar
y=$(xwininfo -id "$id" | grep -oP "(?<=Absolute upper-left Y:).*")
echo -e "Top panel + Header Bar ="$y"\n"

headerbar=$(( y - top_panel ))
echo "Title Bar = "$headerbar"px"

read -n1 -p "Any key to exit"

Results:
Id = 46137366 Wrong One!!
Id = 83886086
Top Panel =  32
Top panel + Header Bar = 82
Title Bar = 50px
Any key to exit
Seems like a lot of gear to find one tiny number! What is the "easy" method ??
This is an updated version of my original script.
#!/bin/bash

sleep .08 # Allow time for the active window to become this window.
id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)

# Move the window to the top of the screen so that xprop gives
# the exact size of the window header bar including top panel.
xdotool windowmove "$id" "0" "0"

sleep .05 # Allow time for xdotool to move this window.
xprop=$(xprop -root "_NET_WORKAREA")

# Cut out the desired value and trim the space before the value.
top_panel=$(echo "$xprop" | cut -d, -f2 | xargs)

# Get the size between the top of screen and the start of this window.
xwininfo=$(xwininfo -id "$id" | grep -oP "(?<=Absolute upper-left Y:).*")
headerbar=$(( xwininfo - top_panel ))

echo -e "Top panel  = $top_panel""px""\nHeader Bar = $headerbar""px""\n"

# Remove the variables from memory.
unset id xprop top_panel xwininfo headerbar
read -n1 -p "Any key to exit."

This should now be getting close to what the script should be! Although, I shall still use unquoted space-less variables in my scripts, as shown in the image below, as I'm dyslexic which does make reading lines like  echo -e "Top panel  = $top_panel""px""\nHeader Bar = $headerbar""px""\n" difficult for me to read.


(1) I appreciate the need to sleep between moving the window and getting its new properties. I don’t understand why there would be any benefit to sleeping at the beginning of the script.  (2) As a general rule, you should quote variables when you use them; e.g., xwininfo -id "$id" and echo "${y#=}".  (3) Maybe I’m just slow today, but I don’t see what you’re accomplishing with the ${y#=}.  (4) For readability, I would suggest breaking down the code into one more step and moving the cut into the first step: y=$(xprop …|cut …), x=$(xwininfo …), then $((x-y)). … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (5) Displaying the result with a read statement is weird. Just use printf (or echo).  (6) Did you see How to Get Taskbar Size and Position with Python? If it’s one of your sources, you should probably cite it. If you haven’t seen it, see if it helps you.

(7) Thank you for addressing my concerns.  (8a) I see that you changed ${…#=} to ${…#*=}, which makes more sense.  (8b) Did you have ${…#*=} in your script all along (i.e., was the ${…#=} in your question just a typo)?  If not, that suggests that you don’t really need it at all.  I can’t test it right now, but it looks to me like the cut -d, -f2 should be enough to extract the second number from the string (even if the label and the = are still there).  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (9) You’re using quotes wrong. When you say, for example, echo "Id = "$id" Wrong One!!", you have (a) “Id = ” (quoted), followed by (b) “$id” (unquoted) and (c) “ Wrong One!!” (quoted). You need to quote constant strings only when they contain leading or trailing spaces, multiple consecutive spaces, or special characters like !, &, *, etc. For example, echo About to sleep... (without quotes) is OK. (You also need quotes when you need to have a string with an embedded space, like with your read -n1 -p "Any key to exit" or a filename like “Start menu”.) … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  You should always quote variables (except for the rare case where you have a good reason not to).  For example, you should say just echo "Id = $id Wrong One!!".  When you want to juxtapose a variable and an alphanumeric string, use braces: echo "Title Bar = ${headerbar}px".  If you want to display quotes, use backslashes: echo "Id = \"$id\" Wrong One!!".    (0) Sorry for not answering your question.  If I could, I would, but I’m temporarily without access to a suitable system to experiment on.

Thanks again for the advice. Yes, the missing * was definitely a typo, It was originally there, but got left out during editing the line while I was trying to get it to work. I use Geany with my own dark text highlighting scheme and variables show as white which really stands out for my old eyes, so I purposely unquote them so that they are very noticeable which makes it easier for me to fix mistakes, I only unquote variables when I am absolutely certain they don't contain any spaces, I learned that one the hard way!! Juxtapose is a new one on me, I had to google it :)
